# MYSQL : How to declare foreign key inline?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I know that is possible to declare primary key inline as

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
    `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);
```

my doubt is if is possible to declare foreign key in the same way, something like

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
   `foreign_id` INTEGER FOREIGN KEY `other_table` (`other_table_id`)
);
```

Comment: What prevented you from simply reading [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html)? _Everything_ you need is there.

Comment: It is a pity that MySQL has not supported this for 20 years, just look at (in chronological order): https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4919, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17943, https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=102904.

The task would be rather simple to address, with not much coding involved. Otherwise, give a clear warning that the functionality is still not supposed to work. Do not feed wrong expectations.

Answer (score 10):

As of today (Feb. 2020), a code like the following would be executed just fine on e.g. MariaDB (`10.3.18-MariaDB-0+deb10u1`):

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS TABLE_TEST;
CREATE SCHEMA TABLE_TEST;
USE TABLE_TEST;
CREATE TABLE TABLE_TESTA(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE_TESTB(
    fk INT REFERENCES TABLE_TESTA(id)
);
```

The syntax you would use would be

```
AttributeName AttributeType REFERENCES TableName(AttributeName)
```

inside a `CREATE` statement.

**BUT** the foreign key would not be created.
You can see for yourself by executing

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_TESTB VALUES (2);
```

or even

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_TESTB;
```

which returns

```
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table       | Create Table                                                                                     |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_TESTB | CREATE TABLE `TABLE_TESTB` (
  `fk` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 |
+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**So, you can "declare" a foreign key inline, and it will be parsed, but it will not be enforced!**

[This is a bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=17943) that has been documented for a loooooong time but never addressed.

Comment: Fixed in MariaDB 5.0 (https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-20729), but not in MySQL.

Answer (score 6):

From the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html):

> MySQL does not recognize or support “inline REFERENCES specifications” (as defined in the SQL standard) where the references are defined as part of the column specification. MySQL accepts REFERENCES clauses only when specified as part of a separate FOREIGN KEY specification.

Comment: Interesting that they stick to the standard for the `CREATE TABLE` syntax but drop support when it comes to semantics.

Comment: I believe your answer is outdated. I can't even find your quote in the documentation you are linking.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE things ADD COLUMN `stuff_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, ADD CONSTRAINT `stuff_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`stuff_id`) REFERENCES `other_table` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Comment: The question said inline